# I have a widget definition showing up outside of my page at the bottom. I can't find what is causing this. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Help.. Probably simple solution, but.

I have a widget definition showing up outside of my page frame boundary at the bottom. I can't find what is causing this. Any suggestions?
It is showing up at the very bottom, and so I have a feeling it is misplaced code outside of the normal 'user' area for plugins, etc.

[At the very bottom, this text should not be here.] -->
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCGpa.jpg)

You can have a look at it yourself if you go to [www.massasje-spesialisten.no](https://www.massasje-spesialisten.no/wp/) and then scroll down to the very bottom.

Comment: check your WP widgets and see which one is set to display in footer

Comment: Done that already.  This is outside of the footer. That is the problem